# I don't know where my particle generator is stuck

Tags: python-3.x, particles

This is my code, it for a piece of assignment, in python
When i run it, it seems to let me input numbers, but then it keeps running, but never spits out anything....

my suspicion is that the len(particles_arr) initially is 0, so divide that by area is giving me an error? but even if i do len(particles_arr)+1, it's still stuck looping somewhere without spitting errors....

please help!!

like afterwards, i still have to compile the average distance between particles per particle, which i'm still scratching my head on how to do it.

sorry, this is my first time coding from scratch.

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Particle:
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        
    def overlap(self, other):
        distance = ((self.x-other.x)**2 + (self.y-other.y)**2) ** 0.5
        diameter = self.radius * 2
        return distance < diameter
    
(edit:

def gen_part(density,box_size,radius,inclusion_prob):
    particles_arr = []
    particle_count = (box_size ** 2) * density_input
    
    while particle_count < len(particles_arr):
        x = random.random()*box_size
        y = random.random()*box_size
)        
        overlap = False        
        for trail_particle in particles_arr:
            if Particle(x,y,radius).overlap(trail_particle):
                if random.random() < inclusion_prob:
                    continue
                overlap = True
                break
        if not overlap or random.random() < inclusion_prob:
            particles_arr.append(Particle(x,y,radius))
    return particles_arr

radius = float(input("Enter particle radius: "))
box_size = float(input("Enter box width: "))
inclusion_prob = float(input("Enter inclusion probability (between 0 and 1): "))
density_input = float(input('enter density'))

partis = gen_part(density_input, box_size,radius,inclusion_prob)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
for particle in partis:
    circle = plt.Circle((particle.x, particle.y), particle.radius, color='white')
    ax.add_artist(circle)

ax.set_xlim([0, box_size])
ax.set_ylim([0, box_size])
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: You never update `density` or `density_input` in the loop, so `density < density_input` is never going to change from True to False.

Comment: On cursory scan of your code,  where exactly do you change either ```density``` or ```density_input```?  Your ```while density < density_input:``` doesn't seem to change.

Comment: thanks!

i now changed it to the following:

```def gen_part(density,box_size,radius,inclusion_prob):
    particles_arr = []
    particle_count = (box_size ** 2) * density_input
    
    while particle_count < len(particles_arr):
        x = random.random()*box_size
        y = random.random()*box_size
```
it now runs, but no particles are getting added for some reason....